# Afterconnect client method with websocket and spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, web, websocket

I have a test which should connect and subscribe multiple users to a websocket endpoint. The test connects the user but doesn't subscribe the users.

This is how I try to connect the users:

```
List<ConsumerStompSessionHandler> consumers = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_USERS; i++) {
    consumers.add(new ConsumerStompSessionHandler(BROADCAST_MESSAGE_COUNT, connectLatch, subscribeLatch,
            messageLatch, disconnectLatch, failure));
    stompClient.connect(stompUrl, consumers.get(i), host, port);
}

if (failure.get() != null) {
    throw new AssertionError("Test failed", failure.get());
}
if (!connectLatch.await(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
    fail("Not all users connected, remaining: " + connectLatch.getCount());
}
if (!subscribeLatch.await(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
    fail("Not all users subscribed, remaining: " +
            subscribeLatch.getCount());
}

stopWatch.stop();
logger.debug("Finished: " + stopWatch.getLastTaskTimeMillis() + " millis");
```

The afterConnect method, which I think it is not executed:

```
@Override
public void afterConnected(final StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
    this.connectLatch.countDown();
    session.setAutoReceipt(true);
    session.subscribe("/topic/greetings", new StompFrameHandler() {
        public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
            return String.class;
        }

        public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
            if (messageCount.incrementAndGet() == expectedMessageCount) {
                messageLatch.countDown();
                disconnectLatch.countDown();
                session.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }).addReceiptTask(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            subscribeLatch.countDown();
        }
    });
}
```

I also tried to put a Thread.sleep(5000) in the for after the connection but it didn't work.

Can anyone tell me why it doesn't subscribe. 
The subscribe url is the same from @Controller -> @SendTo("/topic/greetings").